# mysql - query results intermitently return as read-only "could not determine a unique row identifier (MySQL server has gone away)"

Tags: mysql, database, dll, mysql-workbench

When running very basic query in MySQL Workbench 6.3, at least 2 users have found that occasionally the results will come back as read-only, when you mouse-over the read-only warning, it display the full message:

> "could not determine a unique row identifier (MySQL Server has gone away)"

This is fixed by closing workbench and reopening it.  If you do that and run the exact same query, the results will be editable.

Here are two queries that have caused this issue:

```
SELECT * FROM gambling.Access where identifier like '55512125555';
SELECT * FROM gambling.disposition_log WHERE case_id like '55512125555';
```

I'm extremely unfamiliar with mysql in general, but I've looked everywhere for a solution.  I've seen a hundred threads that address the MySQL Server has gone away part, but I've never seen it combined with the unique row identifier bit.

I've pulled the logs from one of the users experiencing this issue, I'm not positive how to post those here, however the last 224 lines of the log are all the same message:

> [ERR][     AutoCCache]: Exception while running refresh task: MySQL server has gone away

I thought maybe it had something to do with the grant permissions for both users, so I checked those (SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'%';) I get the following:

> ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'user' on host '%'

Honestly though, given that this is fixed by closing and reopening the connection (restarting the program), I'm not sure it's part of the problem.  But then again, logged in as root, I've never experienced this issue.

Lastly, here is the system info for this users machine:

> MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.6 CE build 511 (64 bit)
>
> Configuration Directory: C:\Users\mhenderson\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
>
> Data Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE
>
> Cairo Version: 1.10.2
>
> OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
>
> CPU: 4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 8.0 GiB RAM
>
> Active video adapter NVIDIA GeForce GT 635
>
> Installed video RAM: 1024 MB
>
> Current video mode: 1920 x 1080 x 4294967296 colors
>
> Used bit depth: 32
>
> Driver version: 10.18.13.5382
>
> Installed display drivers: nvd3dumx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvwgf2umx.dll,nvd3dum,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um,nvwgf2um
>
> Current user language: English (United States)

Lastly, thank you all so very much for any help you can offer.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate it.

***Update 8/16/2016***
Still no luck finding a solution elsewhere, and from the lack of responses here I can't help but think I'm not providing the right information.  Even if you don't know the answer to my issue, I'd love to know what other information I can provide to help narrow things down!  Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: I get this same issue constantly when connected to a database on a GoDaddy shared server. It happens even when I query a table with only one row. My best guess is that the server cuts off the connection prematurely.

Comment: Yes, same here, with HostGator. I have PKs on all my tables, have even added Unique as well (redundantly, I expect), have limited rows returned to 10.

The only trick I've found, which is intermittent, is to go to server status and click "Test Connection", which succeeds, then re-open the select query on the table in question. If you hold your mouth right, it _may_ come back R/W. It's a real PITA.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM gambling.Access where identifier like '55512125555';
```

You're not using an index, you're using `LIKE`, so MySQL is going to have to work harder to find data. The larger the data set, the longer the query execution. Potentially this will also return a large data set.

What's likely happening is not a problem on your DB but on your connection end. I've seen Workbench time out where the execution or data transfer is long. Because you didn't get the full return, Workbench will make the data read-only.

You can try to work around this a few ways

1. Set up some sort of index. If you do an `EXPLAIN` on your query you'll probably see it doing a lot of disk work to respond to the query. Indices are designed to help you find data quickly.
2. `LIMIT` your query to a smaller return. Say, get 100 rows (Workbench has a dropdown to help you with this). This will reduce the chance you get a timeout

Comment: I checked the tables in the table editor, both are indexed (disposition_log.case_id  and  Access.identifier), changed the query to not use like and instead read 
    SELECT * FROM gambling.Access where identifier = 55512125555;

The same issue presents after the change.  And as far as the size of the data set returned, it's never more than 2 or 3 rows.  Typically it's just a single row.  Am I missing any of your main points?  Also, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to make sure your network connection between workbench and mysql is good. It just seems to be a bug in Workbench that when a connection is lost it never reconnects for some things. Queries still run but there must be some background process that does not reconnect.